# Passing HashTable data from php.ini to an extension method: corrupted values

Tags: php, c, hashtable, php-7, php-internals

I am trying to make a PHP (7.4) extension use in an extension method a setting from `php.ini` (like `myext.map=key1=val1,key2=val2;`) parsed as an associative array. I want the parsing to happen in `PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(myext)`.

So, I declared a php setting, uncommented `REGISTER_INI_ENTRIES();` in `PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(myext)`, declared:

```
ZEND_BEGIN_MODULE_GLOBALS(myext)
    HashTable map;
ZEND_END_MODULE_GLOBALS(myext)
```

and filled `MYEXT_G(map)` from the `php.ini` settingJR:

```
PHP_INI_MH(myext_update_map) {
// The part that parses new_value into (key => val) pairs is skipped. It works.
//...
// key = val assignments have been counted.
zend_hash_init(&MYEXT_G(map), count, NULL, NULL, 1); // 1 for "persistent".
// ...
// Iterating (key => value) pairs.
    // key, key_len, val, val_len have been successfully extracted from php.ini.
    zend_string * key_z = zend_string_init( key, key_len, 1 );
    zval val_z;
    ZVAL_STRINGL( &val_z, val, val_len );
    zend_hash_add_new( &MYEXT_G(map), key_z, &val_z );
```

Then, in a PHP method, I try to read data from &MYEXT_G(map):

```
PHP_METHOD(MyExt, getMap) {
// ...
zend_string * key_z;
zval * val_z;
ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_STR_KEY_VAL(&MYEXT_G(map), key_z, val_z)
    php_error_docref( NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "ZSTR_VAL(key_z) = %s\n", ZSTR_VAL(key_z) );
    php_error_docref( NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "Z_STRVAL_P(val_z) = %s\n", Z_STRVAL_P(val_z) );
    php_error_docref( NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "Z_STRLEN_P(val_z) = %lu\n", Z_STRLEN_P(val_z) );
ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_END();
```

If the PHP script containing `MyExt::getLibraries()` is called from the command line, the PHP warnings print keys and values as they were set in `php.ini`.

However, if the script is called by HTTP request, in the warning messages, `ZSTR_VAL(key_z)` is correct but both `Z_STRVAL_P(val_z)` and `Z_STRLEN_P(val_z)` contain garbage.

All involved functions are either defined as PHP macros or receive `TSRMLS_DC`.

It seems that the values (but not keys) in a global hashtable get deallocated between module initialisation and serving HTTP request.

I have made sure that scalar values in `MYEXT_G` survive from `PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(myExt)` into PHP method called from HTTP request.

So, how can I make sure that `HashTable` values are really persistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was advised at *PHP internals (internals@lists.php.net)*, `ZVAL_STRINGL` allocates a per-request string; and I needed `ZVAL_STR`: `ZVAL_STR(&val_z, zend_string_init(val, val_len, 1));`.

Then I added `val_z` to the global hash table: `zend_hash_str_add_new( &MYEXT_G(map), key_z, key_len, &val_z );`. The hashtable `&MYEXT_G(map)` was readable (both keys and values) while serving HTTP requests.